# Rota não está sendo localizada no meu site, mas funciona em localhost

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

Tenho um serviço, com verbos **GET** e **PUT**. Em localhost está ok, mas quando eu hospedo no meu site me vem esse erro, somente quando eu chamo o ***PUT***:

> IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 404.6 - Not Found

Segundo os caras do provedor, pode ser esse o problema de rota não encontrada. Veja o meu serviço e o método que é chamado pelo serviço.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Atualiza")]
public class AtualizaController : ApiController
{
    AutorizadorContext contexto = new AutorizadorContext();
    PedidoLiberacao liberacao = new PedidoLiberacao();

    [Route("{id}/{value}")]
    [AcceptVerbs("Put")]
    public void putItensLiberacao(int id, string value)
    {
        liberacao.AtualizaLiberacao(id, value);
    }
}
```

O método que é chamado

```
[Route("{id}/{value}")]
public void AtualizaLiberacao(int id, string value)
{
    var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
        .Where(l => l.IdOrcamento == id)
        .ToList();

        lista.ForEach(f =>
        {
            f.FlagLiberacao = 0;
            f.AutorizouReceberAtrazado = value;
        });
            contexto.SaveChanges();
}
```

seria a url assim:

> www.meu_site.com.br/autorizador/api/atualiza/1000012120/Testando

Comment: O IIS esta configurado corretamente com o IP fixo? IP meu_site.com.br?

Comment: Essa informação eu não tenho, pois é do Provedor(**REDEHOST**). Meu site funciona normalmente e também os serviços **GET**. Somente quando eu vou dar um **Update** no banco pelo serviço, é que dá o erro. Segundo o técnico da redehost, o método PUT está bloqueado, não sei como, mas ele disse que está. Estão abrindo um chamado para resolver e se for isso, este post está resolvido, problemas lá e não cá.

Comment: Tem como ver com teu provedor se eles não tão bloqueando as chamadas PUT?

Comment: Desculpa, eu escrevi sem ler teu comentário anterior... Enfim, já sabes qual é o problema.

Comment: a sua url está errada seria: `http://www.meu_site.com.br/api/atualiza/1000012120/Testando` !!!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, não está errada. Autorizador é a pasta em meu provedor onde hospedo o serviço, então teria que ser ***meu_dominio/pasta/api/atualiza/{id}/{value}***. Isso é o correto.

Comment: @pnet ta errado então o seu sistema! e não está correto porque está dando erro 404! não afirme isso!

Comment: Bem, @VirgilioNovic, errado ou não, tá funcionando. A questão do PUT, tive a informação que é bloqueado por default. Sempre que se cria alguma coisa num site, e isso se coloca em uma pasta extra, para se chamar sempre fiz assim ***domínio/pasta/restante***. Funciona, em localhost funciona. ***localhost:porta/api/atualiza/id/value***, no site publicado o serviço está em uma pasta à parte. Tenho o meu site em ***wwwroot*** e o serviço em ***wwwroot/autorizador***

Comment: @pnet desculpa, mas, isso que você projetou tem falhas, não deveria ser assim, mas, não é porque funciona que está correto, só queria te alertar sobre esse tipo de desenvolvimento para que possa colocar em prática uma melhor prática, mas, tudo bem se está funcionando e quiser continuar assim sem problemas, estamos aqui só para alertar e tentar te ajudar, sobre `put` você tem que liberar isso WebApiCors da uma busca na internet é um pacote a ser instalado e configurado.

Comment: ... continue olha o link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Legal, te agradeço a dica, @VirgilioNovic.A questão da chamada da ***URL** foi a própria **REDEHOST** que orientou dessa forma, quando eu fui hospedar o serviço, mas agora você me falando isso, é mais uma que vou ler sim, agora e ver se soluciono. O que eles me disseram, foi que o **PUT** é bloqueado por default, e segundo eles, estão vendo isso para mim. Mas esse que você postou, já é outra coisa, que estarei verificando já, nesse momento. Obrigado mesmo. Só para registrar, não fiquei chateado não. É que palavras, letras, não conseguimos passar sentimentos e parece ser frio demais, mas legal.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, coloquei o CORS e está funcionando. A redehost me disse que estavam vendo a situação, não sei o que realmente resolveu. Porém, li o link e entendi que deveria ter o CORS. Favor, post o comment como resposta, que eu marco sua resposta, por favor.

Comment: Em realidade a Redehost me respondeu dizendo que tá ok o método ***PUT***